# Need help fetching a person's age from wikidata query using sparql

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api, sparqlwrapper

I recently started working on sparql to generate query for getting the age of a specific person (say, Donald Trump)

The only thing I could understand is that it would be an instance of Person class.
Can someone help me with what else needs to be done to get that specific information.

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Comment: just add another triple pattern with the predicate being the property specifying the age of a person. That's all. Go to any Wikidata persons page, there you can see the property URI used for age. And if you want it for a specific person, the subject of the triple pattern should be the URI denoting the subject: `SELECT ?age {<PERSON_URI> <AGE_PROPERTY_URI> ?age}` - done. Clearly, the age of a person might not be contained explicitely in the data, given that the data would have to be updated on each birtdate

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q22686 wdt:P569 ?birth .
  BIND(now() as ?today)
  bind( year(?today) - year(?birth) - if(month(?today) < month(?birth) || (month(?today) = month(?birth) && day(?today)< day(?birth)), 1, 0) as ?age )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually need to query this from python. How do I know before hand what is the I'd of Donald Trump?

Comment: then you have to search for the ID resp. URI before - you can also do this with SPARQL but it should be clear that multiple person can have the same name, so the result might not be unique - just use the Wikidata entity search service directly in SPARQL

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. I am a beginner in this and couldn't find anything like this in the documentation. Could you please help me with what exactly would be required to get the Q I'd of the item. maybe any links to documentation/examples that would be helpful?

Comment: just combine [this](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples/advanced#Filter_labels_using_EntitySearch_from_mwapi_service_to_provide_Full_Text_Search) with the other query

Comment: @UninformedUser Thank you so much, this was quite helpful. Sorry one last question, if I need the property id of say, age, how do I get that using sparql query?